# Helper function used with Ignited-Datatables do not execute Query

Tags: database, codeigniter, helper

I am stuck in adding column to Ignited-Datatables in codeigniter. Here is what I tried:

Model function to generate datatables

```
$this->datatables->select('id,status')
->unset_column('id')
->add_column('addinfoqty',get_addinfoqty('$1'),'id')
->from('crm_listings');

return $this->datatables->generate();
```

Now i created helper function `get_addinfoqty` to return value from database

Here is my helper function

```
    function get_addinfoqty($id)
    {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $qry = "select id from crm_listings where id='$id'";
    $query = $CI->db->query($qry);
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
       $cnt= 1;
    }
    $html = '.$cnt.';
    return $html;
}
```

How can I execute this query to return either id exists or not? It always returns 0;
Note: When I return `$qry` it gives me the correct query but I cannot run it to get its value.

Comment: am also stucked with this kind of proble.did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$this->datatables->select('id,status')
->add_column('addinfoqty','$1',get_addinfoqty('id'))
->from('crm_listings');

echo  $this->datatables->generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

see my own code

this is my helper method

```
if (! function_exists('human_filesize')) {
    function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2)
    {
        // var_dump($bytes);die;
        $bytes = (float) $bytes; 
        $sz = 'BKMGTP';
        $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
        return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
    }
}
```

in ignited datatable

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
        $this->datatables->select("name, filename, filesize, created_at, url")
                            ->from('sma_documents')
                            ->add_column("Actions", base_url('$1'), "url");
        $this->datatables->edit_column("filesize", '$1', "human_filesize('filesize')");
        echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

should use "" (quote)

so in your code should be

```
$this->datatables->select('id,status')
->add_column('addinfoqty','$1',"get_addinfoqty('id')")
->from('crm_listings');

echo  $this->datatables->generate();
```